# Options for sending data to server/retrying requests in background

Tags: ios, xamarin, background-fetch

We're working on an enterprise app that sends form data entered by the user to the server. The app attempts to send the data immediately after the user taps Save. If there is a problem sending the data (e.g. no network connection), we want to try again X minutes later, and periodically retry until the data is successfully sent. The requests are typically not very large or long-running, but the user is frequently in environments without network access, so retries are important.

It's simple enough to retry API requests when the app is running, but ideally we want to keep periodically retrying when the app is in the background. What is the best that we can achieve with iOS background execution features? Here are some options I see:

- Use `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:` to make a one-time request for additional time. This would give us basically one additional attempt to send the data after the app goes to the background, but not repeated attempts
- Use the "background fetch" feature, and attempt to send any new data to the server when the app is woken for background fetching. Sounds good in theory, but I'm concerned this may be an abuse of the background fetch feature?

Is one of these my best option? Is there another approach I'm missing?

This is a Xamarin app with iOS and Android implementations, though I don't think that has a significant impact on my question; I can write iOS specific code as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there is one approach that you missed : [background NSURLSessions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Articles/UsingNSURLSession.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013509-SW44). And I think this is what you should use.

I don't really know how many shots you can have with this. Here is what I recommend :

- Begin a background task as well (with `beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:`) when you start your background download.
- As long as your background task hasn't expired, you will be able to restart the download, even if in the background.
- If and when your background task expiration handler is called you need to end the background task immediately. At this point your app will stop executing and your download will continue in an external process.
- When the download completes or fails, your app will be restarted in the background and given a chance to handle the result. The thing I don't know is if you will be able to start a new background download at this moment. You should just try or wait for someone that knows better than me...

Also be sure to check the `-(void)URLSession:(NSURLSession *)session downloadTask:(NSURLSessionDownloadTask *)downloadTask didResumeAtOffset:(int64_t)fileOffset expectedTotalBytes:(int64_t)expectedTotalBytes;` delegate method in order to restart your download where it failed and not start over.

Comment: Yeah, I should have included that in the list of options. But, if I use this to make another attempt to upload the data, and the attempt fails, do I have any way to try another request while the app is still in the background? Or do I basically get one shot and have to wait for the app to return to the foreground to try a second request?

Comment: Thanks, a lot of good details. What we actually need to do is POST data to a server, so it would be a background upload task, but the basic idea should be the same. I'll accept your answer if nothing else is posted that offers a better solution.

Comment: There is a sample code too, that should let you try easily : https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SimpleBackgroundTransfer/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013416